# Updating the sum of jTextFields automatically everytime they change (Java)

Tags: java, swing, jtextcomponent, documentlistener

as part of my java learning I made a jForm using netbeans which contains three jTextFields for the user to enter some numbers and then the sum of those numbres is displayed in another jTextField. This is, of course, extremely easy, but I want to be able to do this without any buttons. I don't know how to "update" the sum everytime any of the 3 textfields is modified. Can anyone help me?

Here's my code (the form was done with netbeans in the design mode):

```
package sumfields;

public class Frame extends javax.swing.JFrame {


    public Frame() {
        initComponents();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
    private void initComponents() {

        n1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        n2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        n3 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        sum = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jLabel1.setText("n1");

        jLabel2.setText("n2");

        jLabel3.setText("n3");

        jLabel5.setText("result");

        jButton1.setText("Opperate");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(15, 15, 15)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                            .addComponent(jLabel1)
                            .addComponent(jLabel2)
                            .addComponent(jLabel3)))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel5)))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(sum, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 59, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(30, 30, 30)
                        .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 79, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addContainerGap())
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(n1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 50, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(n2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 50, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(n3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 50, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(32, 32, 32)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(n1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel1))
                        .addGap(10, 10, 10)
                        .addComponent(n2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addComponent(jLabel2))
                .addGap(20, 20, 20)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(n3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(sum, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jButton1)
                    .addComponent(jLabel5))
                .addContainerGap(38, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        int r=Integer.parseInt(n1.getText())+Integer.parseInt(n2.getText())+Integer.parseInt(n3.getText());
        sum.setText(""+r);

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Frame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Frame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Frame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Frame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Frame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
    private javax.swing.JTextField n1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField n2;
    private javax.swing.JTextField n3;
    private javax.swing.JTextField sum;
    // End of variables declaration
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As `@Reimeus` suggested, you need to add Document Listener to each of your text fields. Since you're performing the addition in your `jButton1ActionPerformed()` method, I made the notification of the listeners call this method whenever there's a change to your text fields.

**Note**: *Based on the comments, I've updated my code to include only one `DocumentListener` and also added a `DocumentFilter` to accept only numeric input. I also removed the button that was present in the original code to perform the summation*

Here's your updated code:

```
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;
import javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument;
import javax.swing.text.AttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.DocumentFilter;

public class Frame extends javax.swing.JFrame {


    public Frame() {
        initComponents();
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
    private void initComponents() {

        n1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        n2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        n3 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        sum = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        DocumentListener documentListener = new DocumentListener() {

            @Override
            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                performSummation(null);
            }

            @Override
            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                performSummation(null);
            }

            @Override
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            }
        };

        DocumentFilter numericFilter = new DocumentFilter(){

            @Override
            public void insertString(FilterBypass fb, int offset,
                    String string, AttributeSet attr)
                    throws BadLocationException {
                fb.insertString(offset, string.replaceAll("[^\\d]", ""), attr);
            }

            @Override
            public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length,
                    String text, AttributeSet attrs)
                    throws BadLocationException {

                fb.replace(offset, length, text.replaceAll("[^\\d]", ""), attrs);
            }
        };

        ((AbstractDocument) n1.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(numericFilter);
        ((AbstractDocument) n2.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(numericFilter);
        ((AbstractDocument) n3.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(numericFilter);

        n1.getDocument().addDocumentListener(documentListener);
        n2.getDocument().addDocumentListener(documentListener);
        n3.getDocument().addDocumentListener(documentListener);


        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jLabel1.setText("n1");
        jLabel2.setText("n2");
        jLabel3.setText("n3");
        jLabel5.setText("result");


        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(15, 15, 15)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                            .addComponent(jLabel1)
                            .addComponent(jLabel2)
                            .addComponent(jLabel3)))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel5)))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(sum, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 59, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(30, 30, 30)
                        .addContainerGap())
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(n1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 50, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(n2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 50, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(n3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 50, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(32, 32, 32)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(n1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel1))
                        .addGap(10, 10, 10)
                        .addComponent(n2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addComponent(jLabel2))
                .addGap(20, 20, 20)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(n3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(sum, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel5))
                .addContainerGap(38, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>

    private void performSummation(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        int total = 0;
        if(n1.getText().trim().length() > 0){
            try{
                total += Integer.parseInt(n1.getText());
            }catch(NumberFormatException nbx){
            }
        }

        if(n2.getText().trim().length() > 0){
            try{
                total += Integer.parseInt(n2.getText());
            }catch(NumberFormatException nbx){
            }
        }

        if(n3.getText().trim().length() > 0){
            try{
                total += Integer.parseInt(n3.getText());
            }catch(NumberFormatException nbx){
            }
        }

        sum.setText(""+total);

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Frame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Frame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Frame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Frame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Frame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
    private javax.swing.JTextField n1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField n2;
    private javax.swing.JTextField n3;
    private javax.swing.JTextField sum;
    // End of variables declaration
}
```

A couple of pointers:

- Never trust the input that comes from the user. There's a possibility that the user might enter an incorrect value (*say something that is not an Integer*). As such it is always a good idea to validate your input and check whether the input can be actually parsed. Keeping this in mind, I'ved updated your `jButton1ActionPerformed()` method
- The other alternative is to use a [Formatted Text Fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html)

Comment: Also useful is a `DocumentFilter`. This does the validation as the user types, and you can disallow edits this way. See [this forum post](http://www.coderanch.com/t/345628/GUI/java/DocumentFilter) for an example.

Comment: @Sujay Hey, thanks a lot, you're awesome. I just have a doubt, in case I wanted to get rid of the calculate button, where should I place the new code? Again, thank you so much.

Comment: @AlexTerreaux: Well `jButton1ActionPerformed()` is just a method. You can rename the method to anything you like. Removing the button will have to effect on your code :)

Comment: Since you're doing the same thing for each field, you could just simply use a single `DocumentListener`. Less code, more reuse ;)

Comment: I agree with @MadProgrammer, yeah I should've modified the code with just one `DocumentListener`...ahh lazy! :(

Comment: You probably also want to use a `DocumentFilter` to prevent the user from entering anything other then numeric values, but that might be beyond the scope of the question ;)

Comment: @AlexTerreaux: I've updated the code to remove the button that you were talking about as well as refactored the name of the method where you're performing the summation of the numbers. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 4):

What you are looking for is a [DocumentListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html).

Register a listener with each of your `JTextFields` `n1`, `n2` and `n3` and call your method `jButton1ActionPerformed` to update the result field.

Answer (score 2):

This alternative [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8703807/230513) uses a `PropertyChangeListener` and a `FocusListener` to `update()` a sum of values using `JFormattedTextField`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a focus listener or you can use a action listener to the input [`JTextField`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html/)