# watch out for changes in JTextField changes and run method

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I have a swing application with 5 jTextFields.

there is a button to call a "calculate" method but for user convenience sake i want to have the application constantly attempt to calculate the answer (run a method) whenever the user types a new number / changes any number in any of the textfields. So far I have 5 different KeyTyped Events (one for each jtextfield) in which i call the method.

However I have a problem and that is when i launch the application this will not work for about 10 seconds - the method will just not run. After about 10 seconds it works nicely.

How can I a) get rid of this 10 second lag or b) display a dialog like "loading application" until it is ready?

Or maybe another way because what I did is horribly wrong?

here is the source: [here](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B90Bcs3j7GZ9LURVS2k2M2U5UmM&usp=sharing)

i only included this new "feature" in the LumpSum main window that comes up when you start the application.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: 1) With the current information, we cannot determine where that 10 second lag comes from. 2) Use a `DocumentListener` iso a `KeyListener` when dealing with `JTextComponent` instances 3) You can show a "Loading application" dialog but only if you do your work on a worker thread. See the [Swing concurrency tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)

Comment: i put a link to the source

Comment: You shouldn't include a link to the source. You should strip down your source into an SSCCE, and post that here (as @AndrewThompson already suggested)

Answer (score 1):

This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8703807/230513) uses both a `FocusListener`, to catch <kbd>Tab</kbd> key navigation events, and a `PropertyChangeListener`, to catch editing events within a `JFormattedTextField`:

[image]

Comment: `Converter`, cited [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3072979/230513), is an alternative that uses `EventListenerList`.