# Add JTextField dynamically - Java

Tags: java, arrays, swing, loops, jtextfield

Into textfield i set the value (how many create components)

i have button:

```
    JButton DoIt = new JButton("DoIt");
            DoIt.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                   newComp(textField.getText());
                }
            });

public static void newComp(String value)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<Integer.parseInt(value);i++)
        {       

            panel.add(new JTextField( 5));
            panel.revalidate();
            panel.repaint();
    }
```

How to identify components (name) when i set into textfield value: 4 and click on button? i Got 4 new components but i will use it to next step and i dont know how i will use method getText() to this.

Answer (score 2):

When you add new components, also add them to a `List<JTextField>` for later reference. This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8703807/230513) shows a `List<JFormattedTextField>`.

Comment: If the fields will be accessed by name, consider using a `Map<String, JTextField>`.