# How to Auto Subtract input values of JText Field in swing

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I want to auto subtract `JTextInput` value and want the subtracted value in another text field

Q. How can I achieve this?

Here is my jtextfield code:

```
public class Showdata1 extends JFrame
{
public Showdata1()
  {

 this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
Container c = getContentPane();
  c.setLayout( new FlowLayout());
    //  setUndecorated(true);
      Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
      setBounds(0,0,screenSize.width, screenSize.height);

       opening_km= new JLabel("Opening Km");
       opening_km.setBounds(0,280,258,30);
       opening_km.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 1,25)); // NOI18N
       c.add(opening_km);

       opening_kms= new JTextField("");
       opening_kms.setBounds(200,280,258,30);
       opening_kms.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 1,25)); // NOI18N
       c.add(opening_kms);

       closing_km= new JLabel("Closing Km");
       closing_km.setBounds(500,280,258,30);
       closing_km.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 1,25)); // NOI18N
       c.add(closing_km);

       closing_kms= new JTextField("");
       closing_kms.setBounds(700,280,258,30);
       closing_kms.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 1,25)); // NOI18N
       c.add(closing_kms);

       totalkm= new JLabel("Total Km");
       totalkm.setBounds(0,330,258,30);
       totalkm.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 1,25)); // NOI18N
       c.add(totalkm);

       totalkms= new JTextField("");
       totalkms.setBounds(200,330,258,30);
       totalkms.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 1,25)); // NOI18N
       c.add(totalkms);
 setLayout(null);
  }

  public static void main( String[] args )
  {
      final Showdata1 frame = new Showdata1();
      frame.setVisible(true);

}
}
```

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8703464/230513).

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
int val = Integer.parseInt(textField1.getText()) - Integer.parseInt(textField2.getText());
```

for more please refer https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/converting.html

create a class like this..

```
public class MyTextField extends JTextField {
    // whaterver you want...
    public Integer getValue(){
        if(getText().length()  == 0)
            return 0;
        return Integer.parseInt(getText());
    }
}
```

then you can get int value by call `getValue()` method

Comment: how this will work automatic