# Java Swing Adding numbers using buttons output is in textfield

Tags: java, swing

The title says it. What I wanted to happen is that when I hit 'Nails' button there will be an output of '5' written on the textfield and when I hit 'Steel' button there will be an output of 5+40 (that is 45) on the textfield, and when I hit 'Nails' again it'll be 50 so on.

my code so far

```
**UPDATE: I GOT IT*******************

private int price;
private int setPrice;

*othercodes here*

private void setPrice(int price) {
    setPrice = setPrice + price;
    textField.setText(Integer.toString(setPrice));
}

btnNails.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            setPrice(5);
        }
*************************************

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;


public class Frame52 extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTextField textField;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Frame52 frame = new Frame52();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public Frame52() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);            
        JButton btnNails = new JButton("Nails");
        btnNails.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                int getPrice = 0;
                getPrice = getPrice + 5;
            }
        });
        btnNails.setBounds(43, 70, 114, 23);
        contentPane.add(btnNails);          
        JButton btnWood = new JButton("Wood");
        btnWood.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                int getPrice = 0;
                getPrice = getPrice + 20;
            }
        });
        btnWood.setBounds(43, 114, 114, 23);
        contentPane.add(btnWood);

        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Galvanized Iron");
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                int getPrice = 0;
                getPrice = getPrice + 30;
            }
        });
        btnNewButton.setBounds(43, 159, 114, 23);
        contentPane.add(btnNewButton);          
        JButton btnNewButton_1 = new JButton("Steel");
        btnNewButton_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                int getPrice = 0;
                getPrice = getPrice + 40;
            }
        });
        btnNewButton_1.setBounds(43, 203, 114, 23);
        contentPane.add(btnNewButton_1);            
        JLabel lblTotalIs = new JLabel("Total is:");
        lblTotalIs.setBounds(203, 163, 46, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblTotalIs);            
        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setText(Integer.toString(getPrice));
        textField.setBounds(259, 160, 86, 20);
        contentPane.add(textField);
        textField.setColumns(10);           
        JButton btnConfirm = new JButton("Confirm");
        btnConfirm.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            }
        });
        btnConfirm.setBounds(257, 203, 91, 23);
        contentPane.add(btnConfirm);
    }
}
```

Comment: Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Comment: See also [`Adder`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8703807/230513).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside each button listener, you should call a new `private` method `setPrice()` that looks like this:

```
private void setPrice(int price) {
    getPrice = price;
    textField.setText(Integer.toString(getPrice));
}
```

If you use that to set the value of the `price` field, the text field will get changed for you at the same time.

You will also need `int getPrice` and `JTextField textField` to be instance fields, rather than local variables. As things stand, you're creating a new `int getPrice` every time you want to update it, which is not right: if you move it to an instance field, you can use it inside your `ActionListener`s.

Comment: Can't seem to write private void setPrice(int price), there's an error

Comment: "There's an error" is certainly informative and useful.  Let me get my crystal ball and help you with that.

Comment: I forgot to delete that, im sorry, But i figured it out. my apologies

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the actual price you have at each `ActionListener`

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
  int getPrice = 0;
  getPrice = getPrice + 40;
}
```

where do you get the actual price your `textfield` has?

Instead of the above use this:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
  textfield.setText(Integer.parseInt(textField.getText) + 40);
}
```

Of course your approach has a lot of bloated code, so you can use a single `ActionListener` instead of anonymous ones by checking the `ActionEvent` parameter to see which button was pressed.

Answer (score 0):

you may try to do something like this for each button:

```
JButton btnNails = new JButton("Nails");
btnNails.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        incrementPrice(5); // change the integer insede the method
    }
});
```

and define the method below inside your class(Frame52):

```
private synchronized void incrementPrice(int value) {
        getPrice = getPrice + value;
        textField.setText(Integer.toString(getPrice));
    }
```

this solve the problem that you have. this solution is thread safe.