# How do I initialize an array of javax.swing.JTextField objects in the constructor when the objects are auto-created?

Tags: java, arrays, swing

When I try to initialize an array of `javax.swing.JTextField` objects in the constructor, I get a warning about an illegal forward reference.
I understand that the automatically created `JTextField` variables don't exist yet. But how can I still have a global array of these objects available in my program?

```
public class HRDatabase extends javax.swing.JFrame { 
    private javax.swing.JTextField[] fields; 

    public HRDatabase() { 
        fields = {firstNameField, lastNameField, emailField}; 
    }
```

The variables `firstNameField`, `lastNameField`, `emailField` are basically Swing GUI textfields that are declared automatically by NetBeans.

Comment: Can you defer creating the array until the first time it is accessed? Your accessor (`getFields()` or whatever) can hold the logic you're currently putting in your constructor.

Comment: Show the code that is giving the error. And what do you mean by "initialize an array of JTextField objects"? What are you trying to initialize them to?

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8703807/230513).

Comment: @Jing Ma What is the purpose of this array.  You can get the JTextField components after it got added to the Panel with `getComponents()` though you may have to check `instanceof` on the component to check if it is JTextField.

Comment: @trashgod. My JTextField variables are automatically created by NetBeans, so I don't think I can initialize them myself in the constructor. I'll try to call the variables through a function. ;)

Comment: @JingMa: Don't let the GUI editor dictate your design; limit its scope, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2561540/230513).